# Why can't use variables when calling log function？

Tags: c, math.h

I found a very strange thing. When I use the log function in the `math.h` library, I cannot use variables.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<math.h>

int main(){
    int b=100;
    double a = log10(100)/log10(10);
    printf("%lf",a);
    return 0;
}
```

The above code works fine. But the following code reports an error.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<math.h>

int main(){
    double b=100;
    double a = log10(b)/log10(10);//Just change 100 to variable b
    printf("%lf",a);
    return 0;
}
```

The error is

```
/usr/local/bin/ld: /tmp/cc8j9x4e.o: in function `main':
ctest.c:(.text+0x19): undefined reference to `log10'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Comment: You sure both are using same compilation statement? `-lm` might be needed,

Comment: Or maybe you kept `b` as `int` and then decided to compile as C++

Comment: It seems that gcc will calculate `log10(100)` at compile time even without optimization, but it doesn't calculate `double b =100; log10(b);` https://godbolt.org/z/7W7xdv